# TikZ: Why is the 2nd intersection not found?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to construct a tangent line to the dashed curve but TeX is telling me that No shape named intersection-2 is known.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap = round, line join = round, >=triangle 45]
  \coordinate (P1) at (2, -1);
  \coordinate (P2) at (6, -1);
  \coordinate (E) at (4, -1);
  \draw (E) -- ++(150:6cm) node[pos =.5, scale = .7,
    fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {402,000 km} coordinate (M);
  \draw[name path = line1, dashed] (3, -2) .. controls (5.8, -1.25) and
  (5, 0) .. (M);
  \draw (P1) -- (P2);
  \draw[-latex] (5, -1) arc (0:150:1cm) node[above = 1pt, scale = .75]
  at (4.25, 0) {\(150^{\circ}\)};
  \path[name path = aux] (M) circle [radius = 1bp];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = line1 and aux}, -latex, red, thick] (M) 
  -- ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(intersection-2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The line `line1` should intersect the circle `aux` but apparently it is only intersecting once.  What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `aux` circle visible by adding `draw` to the options. Then you'll see that there is indeed no second intersection, because the point is right at the end of the curve.

You can draw the tangent line in this case by replacing `intersection-2` with the tangent point `M` itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap = round, line join = round, >=triangle 45]
  \coordinate (P1) at (2, -1);
  \coordinate (P2) at (6, -1);
  \coordinate (E) at (4, -1);
  \draw (E) -- ++(150:6cm) node[pos =.5, scale = .7,
    fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {402,000 km} coordinate (M);
  \draw[name path = line1, dashed] (3, -2) .. controls (5.8, -1.25) and
  (5, 0) .. (M);
  \draw (P1) -- (P2);
  \draw[-latex] (5, -1) arc (0:150:1cm) node[above = 1pt, scale = .75]
  at (4.25, 0) {\(150^{\circ}\)};
  \path[draw, name path = aux] (M) circle [radius = 1bp];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = line1 and aux}, -latex, red, thick] (M) 
  -- ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(M)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like that but wasn't sure about it.

Comment: Using `($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(intersection-2)$)` would give you a slightly more accurate approximation of the tangent direction, but for slight curves like this one, it really makes no difference.