# TikZ: using the intersections library for normal vector

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style = {font = \scriptsize},
  dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
    draw = black, label = {#1}},
  small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
  big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}}
  ]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \draw[name path = ell] (O) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
  \path[name path = line1] (O) -- (135:3cm);

  \path[name intersections = {of = line1 and ell, by = P1}];
  \node[font = \tiny, fill = black, big dot = {above: \(P_1\)}] (P1) at (P1) {};

  \draw (P1) -- ($(P1)!1cm!-90:($(intersection-1)!1cm!(intersection-2)$)$);
  \draw (O) -- (P1);

  \path[name path = circ] (P1) circle [radius = 1bp];

  \draw[name intersections = {of = circ and ell}] (P1) --
  ($(intersection-1)!1cm!(intersection-2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On this post [TikZ: Why is the 2nd intersection not found?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121114/tikz-why-is-the-2nd-intersection-not-found), Jake helped with using intersections when only 1 intersection exist.  However, even though I am receiving the error that `intersections-2` doesn't exist the plot is correct.

[image]

If I change `intersection-2` to `P1`, the plot is incorrect but doesn't have a compiling error.

```
\draw (P1) -- ($(P1)!1cm!-90:($(intersection-1)!1cm!(P1)$)$);
```

[image]

So how can I have the best of both words a line normal to ray `OP1` and no compiling errors?

Comment: I am not understanding why you think there are in fact two intersection points. There is only one: `P1` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @PeterGrill I know that.  That is why I referred to my previous question on this topic.  I think you misread the question.  When I use the intersection-2 which doesn't exist, the figure is correct.  When I use Jake's solution from my linked post, I get an incorrect figure with no compiling errors.

Comment: Ok, yes you did say that. Sorry, bad habit of not reading the question. :-)  One option would be to use `shorten <= -1cm` to extend the required line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To draw a line perpendicular to the line from `(O)` to `(P1)`, you don't need the intersections at all. You can simply use the `calc` syntax for a rotated line:

```
\draw [red] (P1) -- ($(P1)!1cm!-90:(O)$);
```

[image]